# Getting problem in extracting frames from videos using ffmeg-python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, operating-system

I am trying to extract frames from every individual video present in the folders of the dataset but instead of frames, I am getting multiple subfolders having names exactly like video names. Please guide!

Here is my Code:

```
import os, sys
from os import listdir
import shutil
main_folder = r'G:\\Umar Zafar Data\\8th Semester\\FYP\\Action Detection\\DCSASS Dataset\\all_work\\'
fps = 25


for folder in listdir(main_folder):
    folder_url = main_folder+folder
    for file in listdir(folder_url):
        file_url = folder_url+'\\'+file
        if os.path.isfile(file_url):
            if not os.path.isdir(file_url[:-4]):
                os.mkdir(file_url[:-4])
                print("Extracting frames from ", file_url)
                os.system('ffmpeg -i "{}" -vf fps={} "{}/%05d.bmp"'.format(file_url, fps, file_url[:-4]))
            
                os.remove(file_url)
```

Output image here:

[image]

Comment: Try using [this](https://github.com/cristiean/video_frames_to_images)

Comment: Also, use backticks (```) to format your code

Answer (score 0):

A few fixes to your code, and it works:

```
import os
import cv2

main_folder = r'.\movies'
fps = 25

for folder in os.listdir(main_folder):
    folder_url = f"{main_folder}\\{folder}"
    for file in os.listdir(folder_url):
        file_url = f"{folder_url}\\{file}"
        if os.path.isfile(file_url):
            folder_url2 = file_url[:-4]
            if not os.path.isdir(folder_url2):
                os.mkdir(folder_url2)
                print("Extracting frames from ", file_url)
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_url)
                ret, img = cap.read()
                i = 0
                while ret:
                    cv2.imwrite(f"{folder_url2}//{i}.bmp", img)
                    i += 1
                    ret, img = cap.read()
                cap.release()
```

Note that you'll need to install the `cv2` package *(which I believe you have given the [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) tag)*, which can be done via the command prompt command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```